# Flot charts: How do you alter styling options after the chart's been rendered (e.g. by means of code injection)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, code-injection, flot

Is it possible to change the styling of a [Flot](http://code.google.com/p/flot/) chart's components on the fly – either via the console or a script – **after** the fact that the chart has been rendered? I.e from somewhere *outside* the Flot chart's internal configs (which initially defined the styling of the chart).

To put my question into a simple use case: I have a page containing a Flot chart which has the wrong color on the bars. Using Web Inspector's JS console, I want to alter the bars (lines?) color from blue to, say, brown. (And I don't have any means to edit the configs in jquery.flot.js.) Now I wish to inject code from the console, that might change the color of the bars.

I only wish to be hinted of a basic code structure as I'm stuck (nope, I'm not a particularly intermediate or advanced user).

Screenshot 1 – the rendered chart, unaffected (arrow indicates what I want to change):

[image: Screenshot 1, the rendered chart]

… [Flot's API](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) says:

`$.plot(placeholder, data, options)`

But I don't want to set/change the *`data`* (which has already been plotted out), I just want to change its color representation from blue to, say, brown. The only effect of changing *something*, that I managed to achieve, was this (terribly clueless) piece of code:

```
$.plot("#chart", { series: {color: "#6C564C"} });
```

Which turned the chart into (Screenshot 2):

[image: Screenshot 2, altered Flot chart style]

I don't know why the chart disappeared, and we don't necessarily need to troubleshoot that. All I'm looking for is the simple structure for altering a Flot chart's options by means of code injection.

Comment: This is frequently asked.  Flot does not provide any methods to manipulate a chart after it is drawn.  The API expects to redraw the chart to render any changes. Luckily, Flot renders extremely fast so this is not usually a big deal.  In your example code above, your call would redraw the plot BUT you left out the data.

Comment: @ Mark: that works as a perfectly valid answer, thanks! Maybe best to post it as an answer, so I can check this question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

You can change the colour of an already-drawn series by changing the data object and using `setData()`. This is faster than calling `$.plot()` again but it won't recalculate the grid and ticks. If your actual data points don't change, this isn't an issue.

```
var data = [
    {
        label: "Your series",
        data: rawData,
        color: "#f00"
    }
]

// Initial draw:
var flotObject = $.plot("#chart", data, options);

// ...

// Change the colour:
data[0].color = "yellow"; // Change only the colour of the original data object
flotObject.setData(data);
flotObject.draw();
```